# Ordinary Differential Equation system with constant decay rates

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to understand how two differential equations interact, in the context of flows between discrete compartments in a population model.

Suppose I have three compartments, $A$, $B$, $C$, which have values of $10, 10, 0$ at $t=0$.

The rate of change in both A and B, when taken in isolation, are such that 50% of the initial value decays in one unit of time, i.e.,

$\dfrac{dA}{dt} = \mathrm{ln}(0.5)A(t)$

$\dfrac{dB}{dt} = \mathrm{ln}(0.5)B(t)$

Now I connect up the compartments, so that the outflow from A goes to B and the outflow from B goes to C,

`A -> B -> C`

implying

$$\dfrac{dA}{dt} = \mathrm{ln}(0.5)A(t)$$
$$\dfrac{dB}{dt} = -\mathrm{ln}(0.5)A(t) + \mathrm{ln}(0.5)B(t)$$
$$\dfrac{dC}{dt} = -\mathrm{ln}(0.5)B(t)$$

In my naive thinking, I would have thought that at time $t=1$, this should lead to $A=5, B=10, C=5$, given that $A$ and $B$ have the same initial values and rates of change.

However, for example, using numerical solvers such as R's `deSolve` and Julia `DifferentialEquations.jl` shows this not to be the case.

Could someone give me an intuitive explanation why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that
$$\dfrac{dA}{dt} +\dfrac{dB}{dt} +\dfrac{dC}{dt} =0\implies A+B+C=k$$

Now, the first equation is simple
$$\dfrac{dA}{dt}=-\log(2) A\implies A=A_0\, 2^{-t}$$ Plug in the second equation and solve
$$B=B_0\, 2^{-t}+A_0 \log(2)\,\color{red}{t}\, 2^{-t}$$
$$C=(A_0+B_0+C_0)-B_0\, 2^{-t}-A_0\,( \log (2)t+1)\, 2^{-t}$$

With $A_0=B_0=10$ and $C_0=0$, after $1$ minute $A=5$, $B=\sim 8.47$ and $C\sim 6.53$.

The **why** is in $\color{red}{red}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.